# Определение имени файла открытого в OpenDialog без расширения

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, файлы

Определение имени файла открытого в OpenDialog без расширения

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FilenameWithoutExt:=ChangeFileExt(ExtractFileName(OpenDialog1.Filename),'');
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне не совсем понятно, что именно Вам нужно, если Вы хотите получить имя файла, то у OpenDialog есть свойство FileName, которое содержит полное имя файла. А чтобы открывать любые файлы (в том числе и без расширения), то напишите в свойстве Filter компонента OpenDialog "звёздочка"."звёздочка" или оставьте его пустым. Если, Вам нужно просто имя файла без пути к нему, то для этого есть функция ExtractFileName, а функций для удаления расширения не знаю. Похожий вопрос видел здесь [1](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=21465). Или, как вариант, можно использовать строковые функции: Copy(<Строка>, <Номер символа, с которого начинать копирование>, <Сколько символов скопировать>) и Pos(<Подстрока>, <Строка>).

Я написал такой код:

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  FName: String;
begin
  If Not(dlgOpen1.Execute) Then Exit;

  FName:=ExtractFileName(dlgOpen1.FileName);
  If (Pos('.', FName)<>0) Then
    FName:=Copy(FName, 1, Pos('.', FName)-1);
  btn1.Caption:=FName;
end;
```

Вместо функции Pos можно использовать AnsiPos.

Comment: @DelpiM0ZG мне нужно после получить имя открытого файла в OpenDialog без расширения. Есть ли для этого встроенные функции?